# c++ Overloading and overriding the operator+

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, overriding

I have an assignment which requires me to do the following,

Character is the superclass of Digit and Object is a superclass of Character.

1. Overload the operator + for the class Character, so that it can add two objects of type Character.
2. Override the operator + in the Digit class, so that it adds the numeric value of two digits and delivers the digit that we get if we finally apply “modulo 10”. 
   (Example ‘5’ + ‘6’ = ‘1’ // 5 + 6 = 11 % 10 = 1)

I have tried to code them out and have different solutions to it. I have made comments in my code and hope someone can answer my questions in the comments.

```
class Character : public Object {
protected:
    char ch;

    char getChar() {
        return this->ch;
    }
    char setChar(char in) {
        this->ch = in;
    }

public:
    //Why must I put Character&? What is the purpose of &?
    Character operator+(const Character& in) { 
        Character temp;
        temp.ch = this->ch + in.ch;
        return temp;
    }
};

class Digit : public Character {
public:
    //Can i use the commented code instead?
    /*
    int a, b, c; 
    Digit operator+(Digit& in){
        Digit temp;
        temp.c = (in.a + in.b) % 10;
        return temp;
    }
    */
    Digit operator+(const Digit& in) {
        Digit tmp;
        //Can some one explain what is this?
        tmp.ch = (((this->ch - '0') + (in.ch - '0')) % 10) + '0'; 
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

Comment: You should have another `const` after the `)` of each of those `operator+` function signatures.  The answers explained why the second parameter must be `const&`, but the first also must be const.  The implied first parameter of `Digit*` (becoming `this`) is made `Digit const*` by that use of `const`

Comment: The assignment says "overriding".  I can't read the instructor's mind, but normally "overriding" means the function you are overriding must have been declared `virtual`, which adds some complications to all this beyond just adding that keyword.  So best guess, the instructor was using terminology in a sloppy way, but maybe the assignment is harder.

Answer (score 0):

//Why must I put Character&? What is the purpose of &?

```
& - reference. operator+ overloading works on two arguments, first one is passed implicitly, while the second one is passed by reference
```

//Can i use the commented code instead?

```
/*
int a, b, c; 
Digit operator+(Digit& in){
    Digit temp;
    temp.c = (in.a + in.b) % 10;
    return temp;
}
*/
```

you cannot use this code. you need to pass by 'const', which guarantee's immutability of second argument

```
    //Can some one explain what is this?
    tmp.ch = (((this->ch - '0') + (in.ch - '0')) % 10) + '0';
```

takes an ascii representation of digit, extracts it's numeric value, adds the numeric value and converts back to ascii representation of sum.

Answer (score 0):

**Why must I put Character&? What is the purpose of &?**
It means the parameter is taken by reference/pointer and the object is not copied.

**Can i use the commented code instead?**
This code uses uninitialized variables, so it will not work.

**//Can some one explain what is this?**
ch - '0' is a well known hack to get the value of the ascii representation of a number

% 10:

if the result exceeds 10, substract 10 (modulo operator)

'+ '0':

convert to ascii representation

Answer (score 0):

```
//Why must I put Character&? What is the purpose of &?
```

This causes the character to be passed in by reference, a requirement of the operator overloading. Read up on passing by value and passing by reference.

---

```
tmp.ch = (((this->ch - '0') + (in.ch - '0')) % 10) + '0';
```

When confused by a line try to break it down. I assume you can follow the assignment at the start of the line so let's look at the expression following the equals:

```
(((this->ch - '0')
```

Read the ASCII value for the char from this. Subtract from that the ASCII value for '0'. This works because ascii has ascending values. See http://www.asciitable.com/ and look for the numbers in the table.

This gives you an integer from 0->9 corresponding to the incoming ASCII character.

```
+ (in.ch - '0'))
```

This uses the same trick to extract the decimal value from the incoming value.

```
 % 10)
```

Adding two numbers from 0 to 9 can easily give you a number >9, which cannot be represented as a single ASCII character. This is the remainder operator and gets rid of everything except the first digit of the answer, i.e. 0->9 is all that remains.

```
+ '0';
```

Finally it adds '0' back onto the resulting integer to convert it back into ASCII.